# How to keep only one record from duplicate rows with value based in another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have `pandas dataframe` as below:

[image]

Now as you can see apart from last column `Value`, all other columns have same `ID` and `Order date`, which shows these rows are duplicate, how can I drop these duplicate rows and only keep one row which has `highest value`.

Note: `Dataframe` is very large with many duplicate `IDs` and `Order Date` like this, in picture you can only see result for one `ID` and Corresponding `Order Date`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this :

1. Sort the DataFrame
2. Drop duplicates by keeping the last of the duplicated rows

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID','Order Date','Value'])
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Order Date'], keep='last')
```